# How do I get out of the answer block?

Tags: discussion, support, post-ban

I made some troll-like answers and they were downvoted. One of them had $8$ upvotes and $10$ downvotes, but it got removed by a moderator so I no longer have the net positive reputation from it. I am sorry for my past mistakes, but it seems like there is no way for me to get back in to "good standing" on the site, other than asking a briliant question, which I don't have at the moment.

I attempted to write this as an answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/965477/unit-vector-symbols-names):

> You should tag your question with (soft-question) or (notation) or both. There isn't really a "more correct" notation; different mathematicians/physicists will write a unit vector different ways, but these are equivalent things for the same concept.
>
> Unfortunately, this means you have to get used to all of them, in order to understand what different authors are saying. Ideally, notation would always be universal.

But I couldn't because of my past bad answers. So I tried to comment it instead, but I can't comment until I get back up to $50$ reputation.

So my questions are: How do I get out of this hole? Also (related), what are ways to get reputation other than answering and asking questions? I can only ask them at this point.

EDIT: I think I am question-banned as well ...

EDIT 2: I just edited a question to add a tag and got a small amount of reputation ... is this a way out?

EDIT 3: The help center recommends that I edit my *existing* answers to make them better, but all of them are deleted. This does not compute.

Comment: Some basic info can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/tags/post-ban/info) and in other posts tagged ([meta-tag:post-ban]).

Comment: Thank you for the help.

Comment: About your edit 3 see [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th): *Are deleted posts taken into account too? Yes, deleted questions (if less than 30 days old when deleted) and deleted answers count towards an automatic ban.*

Answer (score 9):

The main purpose of post ban is to stop the user from posting. It seems that this has been accomplished.

It's possible that in some cases, a user may be able to get out of the ban and make positive contributions. That's nice when it happens, but it does not need to happen. There is no guarantee that the circumstances of your ban will allow you to get out of it. Providing a path out of post bans [is not a high priority](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/86998/259867) for Stack Exchange.

That said: you may be able to undelete, and subsequently improve, *some* of your answers: namely those that show "deleted from review" as opposed to "deleted by [users]".