# How can I get out of a question ban?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, post-ban

I have been put under a question ban, it says that I have reached my question limit so they're no longer accepting questions from my account. In order to get out of this question ban I had to answer questions, edit them and do things that would give me credits. I did all of them for the past 7 months but yet nothing is changing I'm not able to post questions yet,I'm tired now, what else do I have to do?

Comment: You might want to check out this earlier meta question, about the question block: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17030/how-do-i-get-out-of-the-answer-block?rq=1.  Probably better yet would be to consult this earlier meta post: [I have been banned from asking questions, what should I do?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24782/i-have-been-banned-from-asking-questions-what-should-i-do?rq=1)

Comment: Um, you have no questions that is closed/put on hold, and all questions/answers have non-negative scores. Probably there are some deleted questions/answers which are received badly? You can find your recent deleted question in our own profile, under "questions"/"answers". See the comment [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20982/problem-you-have-reached-your-question-limit) for more details.

Comment: Now, reviewing your profile on the main site, it looks like you had a spurt of activity in later july, a bit in August, up to Sept 4th, all in 2017.  That's a great start at contributing, but I'm guessing it would have been best to continue such work (answering questions you can answer, editing earlier posts) to show a bit more of a commitment to contributing to the site?  Of course, I can't know all the details.  Just don't give up yet.

Comment: oops, I see you had paced activity was throughout Sept 2017.  But nothing until this post, today?

Comment: Well, it sure looks like you've gotten some pity votes on your MSE questions.  Is that what you wanted to accomplish?

Comment: yes, @amWhy thank you for your advice :)

Comment: @amWhy I can't find my deleted questions, there's only one option to click at Deleted Recent Questions but there doesn't appear any of my deleted questions, there's nothing to show. How can I find my deleted questions?Thank you in return!

Comment: I cannot see your deleted questions.  Nothing appears when you click on "deleted recent questions"?  How many such questions to you think were deleted?

Comment: I would suggest, if you can not recover the deleted questions, that you work like you did in Sept 2017: try again to write high quality answers to questions, try editing posts (suggested edit), and doing so, you'll learn mathjax really well, and you'll gain 2 rep for any edit that's approved.

Comment: I  think that I deleted only one or two questions. Mathjax is very hard, I'm a student and I don't really have much free time to spend learning mathjax.

Comment: Dear Linda.  Questions are typically not deleted due to lack of mathjax formatting.  But you can meet potential answerers part of the way.  For any polynomial, e.g.,  say f(x) =x^5 -8x^3 +5x^2 -17, all it takes is surrounding each side with a dollar sign: `$f(x) =x^5 -8x^3 +5x^2 -17$` then renders as: $f(x) =x^5 -8x^3 +5x^2 -17$.  Much nicer and easier to read, hey?

Comment: Dear amWhy thank you for replying to my questions, I'm sorry if I have bothered you . From now on I'll try to do my best in order to get out of this question ban. Thank you once again ☺

Comment: You have not bothered me, @Linda.  It looks to me like you've gained some positive rep.  Don't give up.  You've answered well on a handful of posts; I think you can contribute a lot.  I do not know all the details about questions bans, or how they are determined, or how to get out of them (I'm not a mod, so all I know is what you know).  Just don't give up trying!

Comment: I'll keep that in mind . Thank you ! Wish you all the best :)